# Everytime i save my Changes in Svelte, getting the Below Error

Tags: svelte

Error in console.
[image: console error everytime i save my changes]

package.json of my fresh installation of svelte

```
{
  "name": "my first app",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte": "^2.0.2",
    "svelte": "^3.55.1",
    "vite": "^4.1.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Show the code, too.

Comment: Which code portion of code u want to see it? Its just a fresh installation and whenver i save my file HMR did not update automatically and i see this error in console. But when i refresh the page manually I am able to see it my update changes...

Comment: All code that is relevant. If there is a lot, you should first create a minimal example. You also should include the configurations (Svelte/Vite). Unless you used something like `npm create` and added nothing else, there is no such thing as a "fresh installation".